# Infowindow HTML code showing from JSON query

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm pulling JSON data for display on a map, but when I grab a JSON field that has HTML code (ie, `<br>`) the code shows in the infowindow instead of rendering as a line break.

http://www.yourmapper.com/demo/v3infowindow.htm

Any ideas on how to force rendering?

The JSON call is in the code, but here it is directly:

http://www.yourmapper.com/api/markers.php?&lat=38.23282191&lon=-85.7209389&id=152&f=json

Thanks. (Note, I posted this in the old Google Maps Group before noticing that tech questions have been moved here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON doesn't contain **`<br>`** , it contains **`&lt;br&gt;`** , this issue is not forced by google-maps.

You may "decode" the strings by changing this line:

```
yourdescription[i] = item.description;
```

into

```
yourdescription[i] = $('<div/>').html(item.description).text();
```

But if I may assume that you are the developer of this service you better fix this on serverside and return the expected result.

Comment: Duh, thanks.  Just needed a fresh set of eyes.  Your solution is correct, and like you suggest, I need to change the JSON service (for some markers) in addition to using the jquery code you provided.  When we push the dev changes live, I'll update the link example to work correctly for anyone else's reference.